# Upgrade from 19.04 EOL

Tags: upgrade, 19.04

I got away some time and couldn't update my 19.04 Ubuntu in time. Now I'm stuck on 19.04 and can't find a way to update to any  working version.

I fixed the apt update so it can still work (using older repos), but I can't go any further.

I tried :

- upgrading from this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)
- this [one](https://lukehackett.com/posts/upgrading-an-end-of-life-ubuntu-server) too (can't get to 19.10 with dist-upgrade)
- and with the do-release-upgrade (see below)

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1 554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1 342 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1 344 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'disco' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool.
```

I'm kinda stuck and out of ideas, and I can't really do a clean install, I don't really want to loose some of my things that are a bit hard to backup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) and [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/)

Comment: Your only choice is clean install to 20.04. And it shouldn't be a disaster if you save your `/home` directory. Also backup your `/etc` directory, in case you need to look at old system settings after the clean installation.

Comment: I looked both links, couldn't get it to work... I guess I'll have to do a backup and fresh install